# Task Scheduler and Modern Standby W10 wake up events

Tags: standby

I need to execute a powershell script when the computer comes out from sleep mode. To do this I'm using task scheduler trigger and event, and it works on Windows 10 with the usual power management and sleep/wake modes, no problem.

However I can't replicate this under Windows 10 on a Surface RT with Modern StandBy.

- Disabling Modern StandBy is not possible (I tried, but if you have
  some tips please share)
- I tried some tricks on task scheduler using
  kernel power and troubleshooting that do work on normal Windows
  without Modern StandBy, here, it doesn't work.

Any help will be appreciated, I can't seem to find documentation on events that can come handy for this on task scheduler.

Comment: Modern Standby cannot be disabled on any Windows RT device.  So there isn’t any tricks that exist.  Are the same events being logged?

Comment: Thanks @Ramhound, exactly, have tried to turn it off and not possible. Events being logged?  I'll need Event viewer for that right? if so, I'm having issues, Event Viewer crashes on random interaction on the Surface RT, it's a bug (Windows 10 non official), please correct me if I understood the wrong meaning.

Comment: What do you mean “Windows 10 non official”?  Windows RT isn’t based on Windows 10 (I don’t think it is)

Comment: The Surface RT came with W8, an upgrade to 8.1 was available with no option for W10. W10 for ARM32 leaked but there are some bugs such as the brightness issue after wake up. There are other issues like Task Scheduler and Even Viewer crashing. So this version of Windows 10 comes from Windows but it was never officially released to the public, it's leaked and for that I used the term "non official", but "non officially released" or just "leaked" would be more accurate.

Comment: So you are running Windows for ARM (only Windows 10 is that runs on ARM hardware I know about)

Comment: Yes. Windows 10 for ARM 32 bits. Along with Windows 8 and 8.1 are the only ones running on ARM (32 bits), this is on Nvidia Tegra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Progress was made. @Ramhound (thanks) pointed to logs, so I decided to constantly check for what appeared on the logs and found event 506 and 507 related to Kernel Power, from there I managed to make things work, now the task executes after "waking up" from sleep (important: this is Modern StandBy".

But things are not that easy. This release is buggy and while I had it working on a basic test launching notepad.exe, it stopped working after editing the task, this is pretty sure an issue with the release (being non official and with bugs), later it was impossible to repeat the same (step by step), several restarts and constant trying and finally was allowed.

While I got it running, this is one of those cases where 1+1=2 but later it was impossible to repeat 1+1. Keep than in mind if you (reader) decide to try yourself.